# Prevent router-outlet from inheriting static components in a feature module

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, router-outlet

i'm splitting my app into several feature modules ,i'm using only the router-outlet inside a component inside a feature module ..
when i do that it brings all the static components like (navbar-footer) .
how can i prevent this ?

app.component.html

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>

<main>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</main>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

patient-list.component.html (inside a feature module)

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './components/contact/contact.component';
import { DepartmentComponent } from './components/department/department.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/about/about.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './components/error/error.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent , pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent , pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'department', component: DepartmentComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: "patientDashboard",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("./features/patient/patient.module").then(m => m.PatientModule)
  },
  { path: '**', component: ErrorComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

patient-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { PatientListComponent } from './patient-list/patient-list.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: PatientListComponent, pathMatch: 'full',
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class PatientRoutingModule {
```

Comment: That's how the routing works in angular, router-outlet becomes a child of the other router-outlet

Answer (score 0):

In patient-list.component.html (inside a feature module)

```
<router-outlet  name="patient"></router-outlet>
```

In patient-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: PatientListComponent, pathMatch: 'full',
    outlet: 'patient'
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: DefaultLayoutComponent -> new one,
        children: [
            { path: '', component: HomeComponent , pathMatch: 'full' },
          { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
          { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent , pathMatch: 'full' },
          { path: 'department', component: DepartmentComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
          { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
          { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },      
        ]
    },
  {
    path: "patientDashboard",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("./features/patient/patient.module").then(m => m.PatientModule)
  },
  { path: '**', component: ErrorComponent },
];
```

DefaultLayoutComponent.ts

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>

<main>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</main>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

In this way, your patientDashboard won't share same layout.

Comment: What will app.component.html is going to have ?

Comment: because now all i have is duplicated headers and footers and the patient dashboard still the same

Comment: move app.component.html to DefaultLayoutComponent html and in app.componen.html just have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Answer (score 0):

The way I solve this is to have a routing hierarchy such that the head of each routing branch a layout component:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeLayoutComponent, children: [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent }
  ] },

  { path: 'patientDashboard': component: PatientDashboardLayoutComponent, children: [
    { path: '', component: PatientDashboardComponent }
  ] }
];
```

Then each layout component becomes responsible for building the layout and can then put the router outlet where it wants.

**home layout component**

```
<app-home-navbar></app-home-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**patient dashboard layout component**

```
<app-patient-dashboard-navbar></app-patient-dashboard-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This is a trivial example, but demonstrates how you can take control over your layout for different branches of your routing hierarchy.

It's worth noting that you still use router-outlet in your main entry point.

Comment: your solution might work if i have 1 root module, but in my case i have several feature modules and each module should have it's own routing module, then i can lazyload - scale my application easily .

Comment: I use this in my app with a lazy loaded module. How does this not work with multiple modules?